# How to determine the dates of execution of a cron until a certain date?

Tags: php, web, cron, debian

I want to determine the dates with the hours when Crons (of a Crontab) are going to run.

Is there a solution to recover all the dates of execution of a cron? For example, the variable crontab is "15 7 * * *" and the end date is "2018-08-05", i would like to find these dates :

- 2018-08-01 07:15:00 UTC
- 2018-08-02 07:15:00 UTC
- 2018-08-03 07:15:00 UTC
- 2018-08-04 07:15:00 UTC
- 2018-08-05 07:15:00 UTC

All my scripts are in PHP. If there is a solution in php it would be better.. Or an API ? Thanks for purpose...

Comment: If you have start date, please use this code: `15 7 1-5 8 * user command`

Comment: This is not at all what I want to do. I repeat: I want to determine the dates that will arrive with a cron code until a certain date. Thank you for help. But you're right, i need to add a start date and a end date and determine all dates between but how ? That's the question... I want to make a forecast on the execution of my crons...

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to count and see all the dates from "now" to "limit date", you can use this code:

```
$date = new DateTime("now");
$endDate = new DateTime("2018-08-05 07:15:00");
$count = 0;

while ($date <= $endDate ) {
    $count++;
    $date->modify("+1day");
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d 07:15:00"), "\n";
}
echo "There is $count dates";
```

But if you need just start cron in need time - use two cron records:

```
15 7 * 1-7 * user   command #start year to July
15 7 1-5 8 * user   command #August 1 - 5
```

Comment: Ok, I can do this thanks but I would like to interpret any crontab... Not only one translated with an algorithm... but one for all ... Like if I ask with [0 0 * * *] with dates [2018-08-01 to 2018-08-05], 

response : 2018-08-01 00:00:00,
2018-08-02 00:00:00 ,
2018-08-03 00:00:00 ,
2018-08-04 00:00:00 ,
2018-08-05 00:00:00 ,

If i ask [0 0 */5 * *] with dates [2018-08-05 to 2018-08-25], response : 2018-08-05 00:00:00 ,
2018-08-10 00:00:00 ,
2018-08-15 00:00:00 ,
2018-08-20 00:00:00 ,
2018-08-25 00:00:00. I would like to know if there's any algorithm to find these dates...

Comment: @Coeurdelion I don't know solution, which can 100% resolve your problem, but... There is a Class https://gist.github.com/m4tthumphrey/8236756, you need to do some changes for your task

Comment: Ok thank you no problem, the link does'nt work. Maybe i found something ... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.java but not exactly..

Comment: @Coeurdelion Class on your link is for Java. I found project, which can help you (scroll to the bottom of page) https://www.codediesel.com/php/cron-expression-parser-in-php/

Comment: Yesss !! PERFECT That's it I found it at the same time ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codediesel.com/php/cron-expression-parser-in-php/

Here the solution. Perfect for all Cron !